# Test Case for custom object

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, code-coverage

How to write test case for below method

Custom Object  : SAM_Request__c
Global Variable :crossChargeInfoSetFlag , samAdminFlag , samTeamFlag

```
boolean crossChargeInfoSetFlagMethod(SAM_Request__c requestRecord)
    { 
        if(requestRecord.txt_Request_Type_for_UI__c == 'Project' && (requestRecord.pkl_Status__c == SAM_Constants.QUOTE_APPROVED  || requestRecord.pkl_Status__c == SAM_Constants.CHARGING_REJECTED  || requestRecord.pkl_Status__c ==  SAM_Constants.AWAITING_CC_DETAILS_PENDINGWITHULSAM )){
             if(requestorFlag && !samAdminFlag && !samTeamFlag){
                crossChargeInfoSetFlag =false;
            }else if(financeTeamFlag && !samAdminFlag && !samTeamFlag){
                crossChargeInfoSetFlag = false;
            }else if((requestRecord.lkp_Assign_To__c !=null) && (samTeamFlag && requestRecord.lkp_Assign_To__c == userinfo.getuserid())){
                 crossChargeInfoSetFlag = true;
            }else if(samAdminFlag ){
                 crossChargeInfoSetFlag = true;
            }
        } 
     return crossChargeInfoSetFlag;
    }
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create record of SAM Request object.
2. Populate txt_Request_Type_for_UI__c field with 'Project' value and set pkl_Status__c to either Approved or Rejected.
3. Set flag value to satisfy first if condition.
   Invoke this method by passing above record.
4. Repeat step 3, three more times by updatign flag value. or create 3 more different methods.

Comment: Can you please write code for this.

Comment: I've fixed your formatting for you, but being here 3 years, this is something I'd expect you to know how to do properly yourself.

Comment: I am new in Salesforce and got stuck in code coverage. If possible, please help me out.

Comment: @Sharique Please don't ask contributors to write your code for you. That's not what SFSE is for. Please see the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) for more about our format.